# How to change Device in Google Chrome's Developer tools using vb Script?

Tags: vbscript, automation, hp-uft

I am trying to Automate a test scenario to it on Google Chrome Device Mode for simulating a Mobile Device. I need to know if we can automate change of Device using some sort of Script.